# sparse BLAS solver used in a shared library doesn't work (returns '-1')

Tags: python, c, sparse-matrix, solver, blas

I have tried to program a solver-function in C (with Ubuntu in Code::Blocks). I want to call that solver from a Python script, so I have build it as a shared library and called it with 'ctypes' in Python.
At first have tried the example from there http://www.netlib.org/blas/blast-forum/chapter3.pdf (page 12). This is a simple matrix(sparse)-vector(dense) multiplication. And everything is working just fine.
Here the multiplication code:

```
const int n =4;
const int nz=6;
double val[] = {1.1,2.2,3.3,4.1,2.4,4.4};
int indx[]={0,1,2,3,3,3};
int jndx[]={0,1,2,0,1,3};

double x[]={1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0};
double y[]={0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0};

blas_sparse_matrix A;
double alph=1.0;


A=BLAS_duscr_begin(n,n);
for(i=0;i<nz;i++){
    BLAS_duscr_insert_entry(A,val[i],indx[i],jndx[i]);
}

BLAS_duscr_end(A);

int err=BLAS_ussp(A,blas_lower_triangular);
printf("%i\n",err);

if(BLAS_usgp(A, blas_lower_triangular) || BLAS_usgp(A, blas_upper_triangular)){
    BLAS_dussv(blas_no_trans,alph,A,x,n);
    printf("SOLVE... ");
}
else{
    printf("FAIL...");
}

BLAS_usds(A);

for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    printf("%f\n",x[i]);
}
```

It performs `y<-A*x` and returns `0` when everything was successful.

Now I have just changed this line:

```
BLAS_dusmv(blas_no_trans, alph,A,x,1,y,1);
```

To:

```
BLAS_dussv(blas_no_trans,alph,A,x,1);
```

This is a triangular solver which performs `x <- A^(-1)*x`. But this function just returns `-1` (something went wrong) and doesn't calculate anything.

Does someone know how to use the solver of sparse BLAS correctly?

And does the solver just solve a triangular matrix or does it interpret it as a square matrix? (takes the lower half of the matrix and assumes it as a symmetric matrix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read the doc of `dussv()` in your link, page 121.

http://www.netlib.org/blas/blast-forum/chapter3.pdf

`dussv()` requires your `A` to be a triangular matrix, which means

> either USGP(A, blas_lower_triangular) or USGP(A, blas_upper_triangular) must be true.

According to your code, you specified A(3,3) twice with 4.4 and 20.0 respectively, which may be a problem.

---

On the other hand, I would suggest you use more powerful/mature libraries of sparse solver, such as [MKL sparse solvers](https://software.intel.com/node/470280), or eaiser to use C++ [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicSparseSystems.html). Both of them can solve A with arbitrary shape.

---

Finally, python already have sparse solvers in Scipy, why do you want to implement your own?

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.linalg.html#solving-linear-problems

---

**EDIT**

After the modification, your problem becomes:

> And now I think the problem lies in the function BLAS_ussp(A,blas_lower_triangular); which isn't able to set the 'blas_lower_triangular' flag (returns -1).

Please read the document of `ussp()` in page 130. You need to call `ussp()` before any of the INSERT routines.

Comment: If specified A(3,3) twice to try if the values will be summed. (There is an option to do so). I have now updated the code above. And now I think the problem lies in the function  `BLAS_ussp(A,blas_lower_triangular);` which isn't able to set the 'blas_lower_triangular' flag (returns -1).

Comment: @PBassler Please read the document of `ussp()` in page 130. You need to call `ussp()` before any of the INSERT routines.

Comment: Thank you! Now it's working. (Reading now the whole doc)